# Loop function too slow

Tags: excel, vba

In one of my reports that I run daily, I have to pull data from a website.  The site gives the option to "export to excel".  The issue with the export is that it formats time as text.  So without modifying the value of those cells, I can't do anything with that data.  I have to add a "0:" infront of the value of the cell to make it work.  And from there I can format the cell (custom) as "mm:ss".

Right now I am using a sub (shown below) that loops through each cell searching for "??:??" and replacing the value of that cell as Activecell = "0:" & Activecell.Value.  And this works.

The problem is, it is STUPID slow, like incredibly painfully slow lol, and I have an average of 200 to 300 entries to fix.  Takes about 40 seconds per entry.  Off topic, the funny thing is, if I run the sub on it's own with screen.updating=true it actually runs faster.

Anyhow, here is the code currently used:

```
    Sub sub_Add0toTime()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''  Convert exported time to mm:ss by adding 0: to the front of each cell
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim rng As Range
    FindString = "??:??"
50
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("CAHT RAW").Range("F:F")
            Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto rng, True
                ActiveCell.Value = "0:" & ActiveCell.Value
                Do
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                GoTo 50
                Loop While Not rng Is Nothing
                Else
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I need to streamline this so that it runs faster, and like everyone else, I simply have a limited knowledge of the language.

Thanks for any assistance.

xXCDXx

ANSWERED:

So, after I got back from lunch, I tried turning off the applications autocalculator before the macro runs and turning if back on afterwards.  It works like a charm.  I don't think I've ever had as much data leaning on other data where this was a noticable impact.  Below is the finalized code:

```
Sub sub_Add0toTime()

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''  Convert exported time to mm:ss by adding 0: to the front of each cell
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim FindString As String
        Dim rng As Range
        FindString = "??:??"
    50
        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("CAHT RAW").Range("F:F")
                Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto rng, True
                    ActiveCell.Value = "0:" & ActiveCell.Value
                    Do
                    Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                    GoTo 50
                    Loop While Not rng Is Nothing
                    Else
                End If
            End With
        End If
        Range("A1").Select

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is just hours and minutes, why not do something like this

```
With Range("F:F")
    .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Because that actually doesn't work.  I wish it was as simple as changing the cell formatting to be a time format.  I've tried lol...

Comment: Interesting as I do this on a file I import that has the similar issue and I am able to then calculate times.  Regarding the slowness, are they any formulas that are calculating on the spreadsheet? You may want to disable calculation before running the sub.

Comment: I didn't think about that, that's a great idea.  The data is calculating and being pulled into other sheets with lookups at the same time... I will try that.

Comment: Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the beginning of the first sub called, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True and
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end. These generally allow for a good performance increase.

Comment: Thanks, the sub is a part of a larger function, Application.ScreenUpdating is called on there.